# Inline-block elements are not lining

Tags: css

Havent done anything with codes for ages, cannot figure out why items are not lining up. All of the elements within .weff-nedacam-paignus should line up in line, each side by side. Instead of that each next post is getting pushed down to page. What causes this issue?  Changed code all around with no luck :/ I could use tables to solve this issue but would love to understand why this one doesnt work so in future can solve it by myself.

```css
.weff-nedacam-paignus {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  width: 22%;
  height: 288px;
}

user agent stylesheet div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.weff-text {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial;
  line-height: 16px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 0px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
}

.weff-img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(183, 180, 180, 0.42), 0px 10px 30px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  border: 2px solid rgb(92, 92, 93);
}

.weff-img2 img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #fff;
}

.weff-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.weff-title a {
  line-height: 1.3;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.weff-title a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.weff-detali {
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 23px;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: #736a6a 1px solid;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.weff-detali li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.weff-detali i {
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.weff-detali a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

.weff-detali a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.tesanuladudsan {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.tesanuladudsan:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1220px) {
  .masakegen-nedacam-paignus {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="weff-nedacam-paignus">
  <div class="weff-title"><span class="xml-text"><a href="site url" target="_blank">$TITLE$</a></span></div>
  <div class="weff-img tesanuladudsan">
    <a href="site url" target="_blank" title="title"><img src="http://www.robothumb.com/src/?url=site url&size=190x120&alt=[title]"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="weff-detali">
    <li style=" float: right; margin-right: 2px; "><a href="cat">cat name  </a></li>
  </div>
  <div class="weff-text">msg</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far this is best i can do :/

```html
<style>
 .weff-nedacam-paignus{
 background-color: #fff;
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
 border-radius: 1px;
 margin-right: 24px;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
 width: 22%;
 height: 288px;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

user agent stylesheet div{
display: inline-block;
}

.weff-text {
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: Tahoma,Arial;
 line-height: 16px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 0 0px;
 height: 60px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: justify;
 display:inline-block;
}

.weff-img img{
object-fit: cover;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(183, 180, 180, 0.42), 0px 10px 30px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
border: 2px solid rgb(92, 92, 93);
}

.weff-img2 img{
height: 200px;
width: 140px;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #fff;
 display:inline-block;
}

.weff-title{
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.weff-title a{
line-height: 1.3;
word-wrap: break-word;
color: #000;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: normal;
}

.weff-title a:hover{
color: #ddd;
 display:inline-block;
}

.weff-detali{
padding-left: 3px;
margin-top: 5px;
height: 23px;
line-height: 17px;
font-size: 13px;
border-bottom: #736a6a 1px solid;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.weff-detali li{
list-style: none;
margin-right: 15px;
display: inline-block;
}

.weff-detali i{
color: #fff;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.weff-detali a{
color: #fff;
background-color:#000;
}

.weff-detali a:hover{
color: #fff;
}

.tesanuladudsan{
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.tesanuladudsan:hover{
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1220px){ 
.masakegen-nedacam-paignus{ 
width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
padding: 10px; 
} 
}
</style>


<div class="weff-nedacam-paignus"> 
<div class="weff-title"><span class="xml-text"><a href="$SITE_DIRECT_URL$" target="_blank">$TITLE$</a></span></div>
 <div class="weff-img tesanuladudsan"><a href="$SITE_DIRECT_URL$" target="_blank" title="$TITLE$"><img src="http://www.robothumb.com/src/?url=$SITE_DIRECT_URL$&size=190x120&alt=[$TITLE$]"></a></div> 
<div class="weff-detali"> <li style=" float: right; margin-right: 2px; "><a href="$CATEGORY_URL$">$CATEGORY_NAME$ $SECTION_NAME$</a></li></div> 
<div class="weff-text">$MESSAGE$</div> 
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox which will solve your problem and also it is responsive.

- Add `display:flex;` in `weff-nedacam-paignus` class:

So after adding the CSS will become,

```
.weff-nedacam-paignus {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  width: 22%;
  height: 288px;
  display:flex;
}
```

Here by default the flex-direction is row wise so it will add elements on the right upto the width of cantainer and then wrap down.If u want to make the elements to align vertically add `flex-direction:column;` in the class.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<body>
    
    
    <style>
 .weff-nedacam-paignus{
 background-color: #fff;
 float:left;
 border-radius: 1px;
 margin-right: 24px;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
 width: 22%;
 height: 288px;
}

user agent stylesheet div{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

.weff-text {
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: Tahoma,Arial;
 line-height: 16px;
 opacity: 0.8;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 padding: 0 0px;
 height: 60px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: justify;
}

.weff-img img{
object-fit: cover;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 15px rgba(183, 180, 180, 0.42), 0px 10px 30px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
border: 2px solid rgb(92, 92, 93);
}

.weff-img2 img{
height: 200px;
width: 140px;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px #fff;
}

.weff-title{
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.weff-title a{
line-height: 1.3;
word-wrap: break-word;
color: #000;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: normal;
}

.weff-title a:hover{
color: #ddd;
}

.weff-detali{
padding-left: 3px;
margin-top: 5px;
height: 23px;
line-height: 17px;
font-size: 13px;
border-bottom: #736a6a 1px solid;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.weff-detali li{
list-style: none;
margin-right: 15px;
display: inline-block;
}

.weff-detali i{
color: #fff;
padding-right: 5px;
}

.weff-detali a{
color: #fff;
background-color:#000;
}

.weff-detali a:hover{
color: #fff;
}

.tesanuladudsan{
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

.tesanuladudsan:hover{
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1220px){ 
.masakegen-nedacam-paignus{ 
width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
padding: 10px; 
} 
}
</style>


<div class="weff-nedacam-paignus" style="
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
"> 
<div class="weff-title" style="
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
"><span class="xml-text"><a href="site url" target="_blank">$TITLE$</a></span></div>
 <div class="weff-img tesanuladudsan" style="
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
"><a href="site url" target="_blank" title="title"><img src="http://www.robothumb.com/src/?url=site url&amp;size=190x120&amp;alt=[title]"></a></div> 
<div class="weff-detali" style="
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
"> <li style=" float: right; margin-right: 2px; "><a href="cat">cat name  </a></li></div> 
<div class="weff-text" style="
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: auto;
">msg</div> 
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"><div class="as-console"></div></div></body>
```

Its because you used `<div>` and div tags default style is `display: block;`
and `display: block;` means full width of that section so they don't let another siblings stick with them and they go down, So as you said you need table-cell or inline-block. and i suggest you use inline-block bcaz the structure is inline-block here.

Comment: Thanks for helping but no, its even worse. Atm only first row isnt lining :/

Comment: @imbaworld
You can fix it by `vertical-align: bottom;`
Now check the snippet.
if its not explain better or draw it for me so i can get what exactly what you want.!

Comment: Lookins like having issue with explaining, so feel free to check attacked image. https://imgur.com/ug2Nmta

vertical-alight: bot; doesnt solve it.